# why does my random walk only work when i do it like this

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, random-walk

I am trying to create a random walk list of a coin toss to track the number of tails I procure. I have used a for loop to simulate the iterating coin flips and used a random generator for the coin. I initially coded the random walk in the code below:

```
tails = [0]
preceding_tails = tails[-1]

for x in range (10):
    coin = np.random.randint(0,2)
    if coin == 0:
        tails.append(preceding_tails)
    else: 
       new_tails = preceding_tails + 1
       tails.append(new_tails)

print(tails)
```

**This generates an example outcome of : [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
This was not the intended output as you can see none of the previous values are adding on when a tails is achieved**

When i code it in this way it works:

```
tails = [0]
preceding_tails = tails[-1]

for x in range (10):
    coin = np.random.randint(0,2)
    if coin == 0:
        tails.append(preceding_tails)
    else: 
       preceeding_tails = preceding_tails + 1
       tails.append(preceding_tails)

print(tails)
```

**From this i get an example outcome of [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5], which as you can see there is a clear succession within the values to suggest when a tails has been flipped.**

I know this is the right way to do it but I cant tell why because in my previous code I created the variable new_tails to define the value of the old tally plus one and then appended this one to the list.I feel like the problem is that my original code won't recognise the appended new_tails as the last element of the list, therefore whenever I use the preceding_tails variable it always adds 1 onto the very first value of tails.

someone please explain why D,:

Comment: You never increment `preceding_tails` in the first code therefore `new_tails` always computes equal to 1.  Also `randint(0,2)` includes 2, so your coin flip is not 50/50.

Comment: @MarkTolonen The randint of numpy uses left closed and right open interval. Only the randint in the standard library meets your description.

Comment: Oh thank you on the (0,2) I was under the impression the last value was excluded from the parameter. With regards to the incrementing. I understand it needs to be incremented but i'm not sure why it makes a difference. Because does the addition of the new_tails variable in my original code not replace the need to do this?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not updating the value of the preceding_tails variable in your first code example. In your second code example, you are correctly updating the value of preceding_tails after each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @MechanicPig My bad, I didn't register the `np.` part of `np.random.randint`.  To the OP, `np.random.randint(0,2)` is correct and excludes the last number, `random.randint(0,1)` would be correct for the standard library whcih includes the last value.  Nothing like consistency in implementation 

Comment: `preceding_tails = tails[-1]` only captures the last value of `tails` *at that moment*, which was zero.  So `new_tails = preceding_tails + 1` is equivalent to `new_tails = 0 + 1` in your first code since `preceding_tails` is never changed after that.  You don't really need `preceding_tails` in the second code.  `tails.append(tails[-1] + 1)` would work.

Comment: @JDong I understand how usually when incrementing you need to make sure to update your variable in the calculation. however with the nature of the variable preceding_tails, it is a variable that will naturally update itself when the new element is appended to the list (as the variable represents the last variable of the tails list. Therefore with every new element appended during the iteration preceding_tails should instinctively update no?). So shouldnt the code understand which element I am referring to without me having to update it in the calculation?

Comment: @Kay See my last comment.  `preceding_tails` *does not* "naturally update".  It's value is `0`.  You'd have to re-run the line `preceeding_tails = tails[-1]` inside the loop to update it after each `tails` change.

Comment: In fact, you could simplify the body of the `for` loop to the single line `tails.append(tails[-1] + np.random.randint(0,2))`.   Add 0 or 1  to the current last value of `tails` and append it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Oh brilliant that makes alot of sense thank you! Would placing `preceding_tails = tails[-1]` within the for loop also help? as then mabye the code would understand that perceeding_tails is the last element of the iterating tails list.

Comment: `tails[-1]` means the last element.  You don't really need `preceding_tails`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen sorry I meant in my original code at the top? so if i placed the line `preceding_tails = tails[-1]` within the for loop and not made any other changes to that code would that make it effective?

Comment: Yes just move the line down to the first line inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

`preceding_tails` is never updated in the first code.  Move that line inside the `for` loop so it will update to the last value in `tails` each pass:

```py
import numpy as np

tails = [0]

for x in range (10):
    preceding_tails = tails[-1]
    coin = np.random.randint(0,2)
    if coin == 0:
        tails.append(preceding_tails)
    else: 
       new_tails = preceding_tails + 1
       tails.append(new_tails)

print(tails)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

A simplification of the code would be to directly append the last value randomly incremented by 0 or 1:

```py
import numpy as np

tails = [0]
for x in range (10):
   tails.append(tails[-1] + np.random.randint(0,2))
print(tails)
```